# A has 3 sweets, B has 4 sweets, C has 5 sweets. Is it correct if I say: "A has fewer sweets"

Tags: comparisons

A has 3 sweets, B has 4 sweets, C has 5 sweets. Is it correct if I say: "A has fewer sweets" or it must be "A has the least number of sweets"?
I generally mean: are "fewer" and "more" used in group of more than 2 objects this way correctly?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use "fewest" in this context?

Comment: You might want to look at "countable nouns", too.

Comment: so what is the most natural way to express what I mean above?

Comment: The problem is it is unclear what you want to say. Do you want to say that A has fewer sweets than either B or C? Do you want to say that A has the fewest sweets in the group? Do you want to say that A has almost as many sweets as B? Are you asking if a comparative adjective can be used with more than two nouns? Yes, it can if you specify as I did previously. It's impossible to answer your request w/o knowing what you want to say.

Comment: Would you like to know if the phrase is grammatical? Yes, it is.

Comment: I wonder if comparative adjective line "fewer", "more" can be with more than two nouns? I mean that A has the fewest sweets in the group.

Answer (score 0):

> A has 3 sweets, B has 4 sweets, C has 5 sweets. Is it correct if I say:
>   "A has fewer sweets"

yes. Use "fewer" for things that can be counted, like sweets. It would be incorrect to use "more" or "less"

But if you said:

> A has 3 cups of milk, B has 4 cups of milk, and C has 5 cups of milk

Then it would be correct to say that A has less milk than B. Even though you are counting `cups`, the actual thing you are counting is the amount of milk that each has.

Comment: So how to say C has "more" sweets? I think it's just totally fine to use more this context?